# Glassfish Message-Driven bean message size

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, message-driven-bean

I'm trying to use a message-driven bean in my webapp, but everytime it throws me this exception :

```
com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.util.BrokerException: [B4122]: Can not add message 1-127.0.1.1(b0:1a:c1:66:46:a9)-1-1336769823653 to destination PhysicalQueue [Queue]. The message size of 24968685 bytes is larger than the destination individual message byte limit (maxBytesPerMsg) of 10485760 bytes.
```

After some researches, I've found out that the default limit is `-1`, so it has to be unlimited.

I've looked everywhere in Glassfish's admin console but withou finding a way to remove this limit.
Even the "new JMS resource" wizard doesn't ask anything about this parameter.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your message so large? You might want to reconsider how you're doing this.

....

You can update it via the [imqcmd](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1794/aeoes/index.html) command. The value you want to change is MaxBytesPerMsg.

From the [SunGlassFish MessageQueue 4.4 Administration Guide](http://www.filibeto.org/~aduritz/truetrue/glassfish/3/821-0027.pdf) or the [4.2 guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1794/aeoes/index.html).

**Updating Physical Destination Properties**

The subcommand imqcmd update dst changes the values of specified properties of a physical
destination:

```
imqcmd update dst -t destType -n destName
                   -o property1=value1 [ [-o property2=value2] ... ]
```

The properties to be updated can include any of those listed in Table 18–1 (with the exception of the isLocalOnly property, which cannot be changed once the destination has been created).

For example, the following command changes the maxBytesPerMsg property of the queue
destination curlyQueue to 1000 and the maxNumMsgs property to 2000:

```
imqcmd update dst -t q -n curlyQueue -u admin
                  -o maxBytesPerMsg=1000
                  -o maxNumMsgs=2000
```

Comment: I guess that the problem is bigger of what it seemed.

I just have a `List` of 2 Strings ! How can it be so big ?

Comment: You'd have to post your code that constructs the message. But that's a different question :)